# Getting values in php while using `.htaccess` RewriteEngine Rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Getting values in php while using `.htaccess` RewriteEngine Rule

I am using the following rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ page.php?title=$1 [L]
```

It means it will create a page like view

(i.e.,)

www.mywebsite.com/contact

www.mywebsite.com/blog

But how can i get values that is passed in the url and display it inside the page using Get method `echo "Page content is ".$_GET['title'];`

While i pass the value in the url like www.mywebsite.com/view,

It is just displaying > Page content is page.php

What mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some urls that don't need to be rewritten are getting rewritten. You probably want to change your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?title=$1 [L]
```

- The `[^/.]` ensures that there is no dot in the path
- The `+` ensures that there is at least one character
- The `/?` allows an optional trailing slash

Comment: If i already have a folder named blog and if i pass the value www.mywebsite.com/blog it will affect right, How can i escape from this ? (while i do RewriteCond %{blog} !-d ) still it didn't work

Comment: `if i pass the value www.mywebsite.com/blog it will affect right, How can i escape from this ?` Not understanding what you mean here, can you please give more detail?

Comment: If i have a folder named **blog** it is not working if i use **www.mywebsite.com/blog**